# Is having a lot of Activities ok

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I am wondering if having a lot of Activities is better than having a lot of different logic inside one activity.

My dilemma:
I am creating an application at work, if I use separate Activity for each major implementation in it (eg 5 activities with video players but each needs a separate logic to it or even 2 video players in same activity) then I will end up within the range of about 40 activities if not more.
On the other hand the logic that I can separate (eg Video player) i put into its own library so it can be called from any activity. But if I put similar Items in the same Activity the code for it would run into the couple thousand lines and be difficult to debug.

So I guess my question is having a lot of Activities ok (the activity stack will have 8 activities at the max) or will this slow down my application significantly.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It should be OK. Number of activities loaded won't impact any performance (as long as they are with-in memory allocated for that process). If required Dalvik GC unused objects.

Comment: Does that mean that if i go into activity 8 then the GC could remove all data from Activity 1 to free up memory?

Comment: It is not guaranteed. Dalvik will decide. If it had to and there are references to Activity 1, then your application will be force closed by Dalvik.

Comment: I see. So any persistent data like which tab I am on and such will need to be saved into shared preferences or something like that? Also lets say I have a video player, is it a good idea to close it and clear its memory when moving to the next level activity and then recreate it when moving back?

Comment: Yes, that is what highly recommended instead of keeping it in classes as static data.

Comment: Yes, if video player reference is not required and it is not referenced from other activity, Dalvik will do cleanup for you. You don't need to worry. If switch between creation and deletion is less,  then I would suggest don't null the reference, otherwise null the reference.